# Progress on "Un-Alching" ML?

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory

So, a couple of years ago I watched both Ali Rahimi's NIPS speech "[Machine Learning is Alchemy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7psGHgatGM)",
(where he talks about how the field lacks a solid, overarching, theoretical foundation) and the [IAS lecture series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pkgJDgRhEo&list=PLdDZb3TwJPZ7aAxhIHALBoh8l6-UxmMNP) on the debate that Rahimi's speech spurred. Now that I'm in the final year of my undergrad and looking to apply to PhD programs in order to work on ML theory, I was wondering how much progress has been made on the examples given in the lectures. For instance, Rahimi mentions that, at the time, the reason that batch norm works was mostly a mystery but I know that [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11604) has managed to shed some light on the subject. I'm also aware that there's been a good amount of research into the conditions that make training robust models possible, and I know that there's been some efforts to use category theory to establish a more cohesive view of ML (I'm particularly interested in this).

Comment: Here is a link to the full playlist that the OP refers to:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdDZb3TwJPZ7aAxhIHALBoh8l6-UxmMNP